# Terraform azurerm azurerm_data_factory_dataset_binary prameters definition

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-data-factory

So i've been trying to define a dataset in terraform for azure datafactory but I keep running into the issue when defining the dynamic parameters when planning the terraform.

Terraform plan output:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on xxxxxx-xxxxxxx.tf line 69, in resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_binary" "xxxxxxx_dataset_source":
│   69:     parameters = <<PARAMETERS
│   70:     {
│   71:         "fileSystem": {
│   72:             "type": "string"
│   73:         },
│   74:         "directory":{
│   75:             "type": "string"
│   76:         }
│   77:     }
│   78:     PARAMETERS
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "parameters": map of string required.
```

Definition of the dataset:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_binary" "xxxxxxx_dataset_source" {
    name = join("", [var.config.name, "_storageacount_dataset_source"])
    resource_group_name = var.common.resource_group_name
    linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2.xxxxxx_storageacount_linkedservice_source.name
    data_factory_name =  var.config.datafactory_name

    parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
        "fileSystem": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "directory":{
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
    PARAMETERS

    azure_blob_storage_location {
        container = "@dataset().fileSystem"
        path = "@dataset().directory"
        filename = "/"
    }
}
```

Documentation is unclear as how this should be defined. I've see other people talk about parameters_values but when trying to use that it say's it's not expected here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per the error message, mapping string value is required for the parameter declared. I don’t see any value assigned to filesystem and directory. Can you add value to filesystem name and directory name and try? Refer: https://blog.johnfolberth.com/how-to-dynamically-assign-azure-policy-via-terraform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way of doing it was this way:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_binary" "xxxxxxx_dataset_source" {
    name = join("", [var.config.name, "_storageacount_dataset_source"])
    resource_group_name = var.common.resource_group_name
    linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2.xxxxxx_storageacount_linkedservice_source.name
    data_factory_name =  var.config.datafactory_name

    parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
        "fileSystem": "",
        "directory": ""
    }
    PARAMETERS

    azure_blob_storage_location {
        container = "@dataset().fileSystem"
        path = "@dataset().directory"
        filename = "/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your anwer